# Programmatically list WMI classes and their properties

Tags: vbscript, wmi

Is there any known way of listing the WMI classes and their properties available for a particular system? Im interested in a vbscript approach, but please suggest anything really :)

P.S. Great site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

[WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en)

A part of this nifty utility allows you to browse namespaces/classes/properties on the local and remote PCs, not to mention generating WMI code in VBScript/C#/VB on the fly.  Very useful.

Also, the source code used to create the utility is included in the download, which could provide a reference if you wanted to create your own browser like interface.

Answer (score 2):

This MSDN page walks through enumerating the available classes: [How to: List the Classes in a WMI Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429532.aspx)

for retrieving properties from a class:

```
ManagementPath l_Path = new ManagementPath(l_className);
ManagementClass l_Class = new ManagementClass(myScope, l_ManagementPath, null);
foreach (PropertyData l_PropertyData in l_Class.Properties)
{
    string l_type = l_PropertyData.Type.ToString());
    int l_length = Convert.ToInt32(l_PropertyData.Qualifiers["maxlen"].Value);           
}
```